# Mean square convergence not higher-order mean

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

There are numerous examples of sequences random variables $\{X_n\}_n$ converging *in mean* to a random variable $X$, i.e., $\mathbb{E}[|X_n-X|]\to 0$, but not *in mean square*, i.e., $\mathbb{E}[(X_n-X)^2] \not\to 0$ (the converse is always true). I'm using the definitions reported in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_mean).

I would like to know whether we can come up with an example where $\{X_n\}_n$ converges to $X$ in the mean square sense, but not in the $p$-th mean, for some $p>2$.

Can we draw some additional assumptions on $\{X_n\}_n$ so that convergence in the mean square sense entails convergence in the $p$-order mean for $p>2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a discrete random variable $\xi_{p,v}$ with parameters $p$ and $v$, which takes value $v > 0$ with probability $p > 0$, and takes zero value otherwise. Obviously, $E|\xi_{p,v}|^s = p v^s$.

Take a random variable $X$ being constant zero, and a sequence $X_n$ of random variables with the above-mentioned distribution:
$$
\begin{cases}
  X_n \equiv \xi_{p_n, v_n} \\
  p_n = \frac{1}{n^s \ln n} \\
  v_n = n
\end{cases}
$$

It is easy to calculate its mean:
$$E|X_n|^t = \frac{n^{t-s}}{\ln n}$$

So $\mathbb{E}[|X_n-X|^s] \to 0$ but $\mathbb{E}[|X_n-X|^t] \to \infty$ for any $t > s$. Now put $s = 2$, $t = 3$ here, and you are done.